# Solve for $x, y \in \mathbb R$: $x^2+y^2=2x^2y^2$ and $(x+y)(1+xy)=4x^2y^2$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> Solve the following system of equations. $$\large \left\{ \begin{aligned} x^2 + y^2 &= 2x^2y^2\\ (x + y)(1 + xy) &= 4x^2y^2 \end{aligned} \right.$$

From the system of equations, we have that

$$\left\{ \begin{align*} (x + y)^2 \le 2(x^2 + y^2) = 4x^2y^2\\ 4x^2y^2 = (x + y)(1 + xy) \le \frac{[(x + 1)(y + 1)]^2}{4} \le \frac{(x + y + 2)^4}{4^3} \end{align*} \right.$$

$$\implies (x + y)^2 \le \frac{(x + y + 2)^4}{4^3} \implies |x + y| \le \left|\frac{x + y + 2}{2^3}\right|$$

I don't know what to do next. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: The first equation can be transformed to $(2x^2-1)(2y^2-1)=1$ if that helps at all.

Comment: It would help to know what kind of solutions you are looking for - are $x, y \in \mathbb R$, for example.

Comment: I am looking for $x, y \in \mathbb R$, but it's okay if $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers.

Comment: Please come up with better titles for your homework problems other than commands followed by numbers

Comment: I can't. If I type both equations into the title, it would exceed the number of character allowed. The title, as told, should be informative and let the users know the main point of the question. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are symmetric equations, so denoting $s=x+y,p=xy$ we have
$$s^2-2p=2p^2$$
$$s(1+p)=4p^2$$
Now eliminate $s$:
$$s^2=2p^2+2p=\left(\frac{4p^2}{1+p}\right)^2$$
$$2p(1+p)^3=16p^4$$
If $p=0$ then $s=0$ and obviously $x=y=0$. Otherwise, divide by $p$:
$$(1+p)^3=(2p)^3$$
Assuming we are only solving in the reals:
$$1+p=2p\qquad p=1,s=2$$
By Viète's formulas, $x$ and $y$ are the roots of $t^2-2t+1$, whereby we get $x=y=1$.

Comment: You lost $x=y=0$ by "eliminating $s$".

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first equation is equivalent to $(x+y)^2=2xy(1+xy)$.

Now multiplying the second equation by the previous relation yields: $$(x+y)^3=(2xy)^3$$ thus $x+y=2xy$ and then: $$(x+y)^2=2\times 2x^2y^2=2(x^2+y^2)\iff (x-y)^2=0$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
(x+y)^2(1+xy)^2&=(4x^2y^2)^2\\
(x^2+y^2+2xy)(1+xy)^2&=16x^4y^4\\
(2x^2y^2+2xy)(1+xy)^2&=16x^4y^4\\
2xy(1+xy)^3&=16x^4y^4
\end{align*}
So, $xy=0$ or $1+xy=2xy$.

$xy=0$ or $1$.

If $xy=0$, $x=y=0$.

If $xy=1$, $x=y=1$.

Answer (score 2):

> My simple solution is $(\!x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2x^{2}y^{2}\!)+ \left (\!(\!x+ y\!)(\!1+ x^{2}y^{2}\!)\!\right )= (\!x+ y- 2xy\!)(\!3xy+ x+ y+ 1\!)$